# Earlyish ‘90s PC Space War / Battle Game

Tags: story-identification, video-games

This was a PC game I remember from the earlyish '90s (1992–1993 or somewhere around then). I remember some specific pieces but not the overall gameplay. It was a game where you built up your army (or maybe empire) and sent ships out for space battles.

The two distinct elements I remember are:

- There was a specific self-destruct sequence you could undertake for your spaceships. I remember this serving a purpose; i.e., you could get to a point in the game where it made more sense to self-destruct rather than continue. On the screen, it revealed a series of numbers you had to type in. It was 'done up' and presented as a measure of last resort
- I also remember a lot of purples and yellows from the game. That might sound laughable, but I believe the screen was divided into multiple panels, trying to look like 'real' computer screens  on a spaceship. I believe a lot of that framing was in purples or yellows perhaps?

I know that isn't much to go on but I've been digging and just can't find anything. I remember playing Overlord in this time period, but I don't believe the above elements are from that game, but I could be wrong....

Thanks in advance! Hopefully this is enough to job someone's memory out there.

Comment: EGA Trek (and possibly other Trek variants) had self destruct, multiple panels, and purple and yellow in their color scheme. You only had one ship though.

Answer (score 9):

This sounds like one of the *Star Fleet* games, *[Star Fleet I:  The War Begins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Fleet_I:_The_War_Begins)* (1985) or the sequel *[Star Fleet II:  Krellan Commander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Fleet_II:_Krellan_Commander)* (1989).  If you played it in the early 1990s, I would bet on the second game.  ([Both games are available as abandonware.](https://www.myabandonware.com/search/q/star+fleet))

The appearance of the game interface sounds like what you describe, with the colorful display broken up into panels like the instruments on a starship.  There was also more purple than you typically saw in video games.

[image: Star Fleet II: Krellan Commander]

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Self-destructing was also an option in at least one of the games, if a mission was hopeless, although I don't remember how the interface worked.  (The two *Star Fleet* games seemed to me to be intellectual descendants of the 1971 BASIC-programmed *[Star Trek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_(1971_video_game))* video game, which had similar grid attacks and also a self-destruct option, and I can only remember the self-destruct sequence from the earlier game.)

Comment: Hi Buzz - these answers always intrigue me: how on Earth do you remember a game that came out _thirty years ago_? Let alone recognize it from a fairly basic description? I am in awe of anyone who can remember last week (perils of getting old), let alone stuff like this. Excelsior to you, from a mere mortal.

Comment: Never played those games, but boy do those kinds of UIs bring back memories.

Comment: Those look like good games but I believe I'm remembering something different. It wasn't text based, definitely had a graphical, VGA interface. I don't believe it was a known IP like Star Trek either. Was there ever a newer version of Star Fleet or anything like that?

Comment: @spratty personally, I can remember several of the games I played around this period (Secret of Monkey Island, for example) far better than most of the ones I've played since.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to figure out the exact same game and I think it was VGA Planets. It was incredibly fun to play!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you please add some details, specifically of the self-destruct mechanism, that show how VGA Planets matches the question?  Please try to address as many of the points of the question as possible, including the colour scheme.